# Global let variable in typescript

Tags: typescript

The drawback I have is that, after usingEffect, the values ​​of rubro1 and rubro2 are not changed. That is, changes in useEffect of rubro1 and rubro2 are only affected in useEffect.

Is there a way to change rubro1 and rubro2 in useEffect and then see that change throughout the element? Or do I just have to use hooks ?

```
let rubro1=""
let rubro2=""

const[ thereIsRubros, setThereIsRubros]=useState(false)


useEffect(() => {
  
  getItem("rubro1").then(res => {
    if(res!=null || res!= undefined){
      rubro1=res
      setThereIsRubros(true)
      getItem("rubro2").then(res => {
        if(res!=null || res!= undefined){
          rubro2=res
        }
        })
    }
  })
}, []);

if (tehreIsRubros){
 if(rubro1!=""&&rubro2==""){
  return (//Return some HTML code)
}
 }
```

Comment: Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) how to create a minimal example, so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove variable and work only with costants

note that I'm using only one useState so you'll be able to update both rubro1 & rubro2 with one instruction and avoid multiple re-renderings

```
const [thereIsRubros, setThereIsRubros] = useState({rubro1: undefined, rubro2: undefined})


    useEffect(() => {

        getItem("rubro1").then(res => {
            if(res){
                setThereIsRubros({...thereIsRubros, rubro1:res})
                getItem("rubro2").then(res => {
                    if(res){
                        setThereIsRubros({...thereIsRubros, rubro2:res})
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }, []);

    if (tehreIsRubros.rubro1 && tehreIsRubros.rubro2){
        return (//Return some HTML code)
    }
```

moreover remove `if(res!=null || res!= undefined)`
just do `if(res)`, it will check `if(res!=null && res!= undefined)` that I guess is your goal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update your component every time you set a new value, you have to use `useState`, if you don't want to update your component every time you set a new value but you want to keep a value between re-renderings, then use `useRef`.

If you do what you're doing right now, `rubro1` and `rubro2` are gonna be re-initialized to empty string with every re-render of the component.

Side note, you can use `async/await` to improve the legibility of your code.

The following code correctly sets the right values for the variables after every update:

```
  const [rubro1, setRubro1] = useState("");
  const [rubro2, setRubro2] = useState("");

  const [thereIsRubros, setThereIsRubros] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    getItem("rubro1").then((res) => {
      if (res != null || res != undefined) {
        setRubro1(res);
        setThereIsRubros(true);
        getItem("rubro2").then((res) => {
          if (res != null || res != undefined) {
            setRubro2(res);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (thereIsRubros) {
    if (rubro1 != "" && rubro2 == "") {
      return; // do stuff
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Lars. How can I use useRef?

Comment: @JAOdev the react guide on hooks has a nice explanation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref and also  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables better than what I could be able to get in a small comment. But basically, you create a ref with `const rubro1Ref = useRef('')` and then, use it and set it through the `current` key: `rubro1Ref.current = 'new-value'`

Comment: Is it advisable to use UseRef when we don't want to render? It is because the rendering consume resources?

Comment: @JAOdev It's not only about performance, but also having code that clearly communicates its intention. If a re-render is not needed, then, don't use `useState` not only because of the performance hit but also because it's clearer and what you intend the code to do (or not to do in this case)